# Cannot work out how to compare 2 dimensional arrays of different sizes

Tags: java, javafx, tetris

So I am building a project in order to build a tetris style game, and I want to be able to test whether the shape will be able to be added to a 5 x 5 grid. The shape is modelled by a 2D array, where a 1 is considered to be a single block of the shape (the shapes are made of a few blocks). The shapes are modelled with a 3 x 3 grid. The thing I must do is check the grid for whether the shape will be able to fit on top of it. Take for example placing a line shape at the top square of the grid, the line will go out of bounds and should not work, or another example is that the grid may already have a shape on it and so the line should not be able to be put on top of it.

This is the code that I've got thus far, and it is not working, I'm just really having a tough time conceptualising what to do. Thank you in advance.

Please note that cols is the number of columns in the grid (5) and rows is the same (5). Game piece is the shape, and the co-ordinates is where the user has clicked on the 5x5 grid.

Also: The anchor point of the shape is 1,1 of the 3x3 grid (so the anchor point is right in the middle of the grid). And get(int x, int y) method is getting the value stored in the 5x5 grid.

Sorry if this was not made clear in the beginning but I am trying to basically see whether the shape stored in the 3x3 grid (made up of blocks) can be placed on top of the 5x5 grid. The 3x3 grid that contains the block has a centre anchor point, so it would be 1,1 (since arrays start with 0). If the 5x5 grid has other blocks that are at the same co-ordinate of the new shape being added, then I want it to return false or if the shape becomes out of bounds when being placed on the 5x5 grid, but if it can be added successfully then it will return true.

```
public boolean canPlayPiece (GamePiece piece, int x, int y) {

        logger.info("canPlayPiece - Block clicked coordinates: "  + x + "," + y);
        // Piece co-ordinates are 3 x 3, each element that is 1 means there is a block there
        int[][] pieceCoordinates = piece.getBlocks();

        // For loop to iterate through the grid
        // first looping through x values
        for (int i = x - 1; i < cols; i++) {

            System.out.println("i= " + i);

            // nested for loop to find the y values stored inside the x
            for (int j = y - 1; j < rows; j++) {

                System.out.println("j: " + j);


                if (pieceCoordinates[x][y] == 1 && get(i,j) != 0) {


                    logger.info("canPlayPiece: FALSE");
                    return false;


                }

            }

        }
        logger.info("canPlayPiece: TRUE");
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: and where is the anchor point in the game piece. Is it the middle so index [1][1]. (I mean the relative point in the piece that should match up with the given x and y value when placed in the grid)

Comment: Yes! It is 1,1 (so it is in the middle of the 3x3 grid).

Comment: What is not working exactly? Is it located inside the only supplied piece of code `canPlayPiece` ? Can you [edit] and describe, please!

Comment: Hey I just added some edits, please excuse my inexperience, it is my first time posting a question.

Comment: @iiicecream I hope my answer (down below) works for you. (Please also read the description down below)

Comment: @iiicecream I made a small mistake while posting my answer where I changed something  by accident. It should work now directly.

Answer (score 1):

Ok i made the following for you:

```
public boolean canPlayPiece(GamePiece piece, int x, int y) {
    int[][] pc = piece.getBlocks();
    
    final int w = 3, h = 3, e = w - 1;
    final int offX = -1, offY = -1; // The offset of the left top corner from 'x' and 'y'
    int i, si, ei, ax, ay, rx, ry;
    for (ei = w * h - 1; ei >= 0 && pc[ei / w][ei % w] == 0; ei--);
    for (si = 0; si <= ei && pc[si / w][si % w] == 0; si++);
    for (i = si + 1, ax = si % w; ax > 0 && i <= ei; i++) if (pc[i / w][rx = i % w] != 0) { si += Math.min(rx - ax, 0); ax = rx; }
    for (i = ei - 1, ax = ei % w; ax < e && i >= si; i--) if (pc[i / w][rx = i % w] != 0) { ei += Math.max(rx - ax, 0); ax = rx; }
    if (si > ei) return true; // There is no block in the piece's grid
    int sx = si % w, sy = si / w, ex = ei % w, ey = ei / w; // The bounds of the shape inside of pc
    int asx = x + offX + sx, asy = y + offY + sy, aex = asx + ex - sx, aey = asy + ey - sy;
    if ((asx | asy | aex | aey | cols - 1 - aex | rows - 1 - aey) < 0) return false; // Would be out of bounds
    for (rx = sx, ax = asx; rx <= ex; rx++, ax++) {
        for (ry = sy, ay = asy; ry <= ey; ry++, ay++) {
            // if (grid[ay][ax] != 0 && pc[ry][rx] != 0) return false; // Block overlaps another block
            if (get(ax, ay) != 0 && pc[ry][rx] != 0) return false; // Block overlaps another block
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

1. First it figues out the bounds of the shape inside of 'pc' grid (the grid returned by 'piece.getBlocks()')
2. If there is no shape inside of 'pc' it will return true, since an empty shape can be placed anywhere (change the return value to false, if you want to return false in that case)
3. If the inner shape would go out of bounds, when being inserted, it will return false
4. In the end it will walk through both the grid (using your 'get(x: int, y: int) function) and 'pc' to check whether the shape in 'pc' overlaps with any preexisting blocks inside the grid. And if it doesn't it returns true.

---

**I really hope that this works for you. I tested it out and it worked at least for me.**

Comment: Hey thanks a lot man, I can tell you put a lot of effort into this, people like you are why the internet is so great! It's a lot for me to understand and I will try making it work in my code, thanks a lot again.

Comment: @iiicecream I made a mistake while posting it here. It should work now

Comment: @iiicecream you need to add the offX and offY in one of the last lines. Just replace the '-' with a '+'. I updated my answer, so that it should work now. Hope you figured that out.

Comment: Thanks a lot my friend :)